# Evaluating Line Integrals using Green's Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

I am currently learning about Green's Theorem, Curl and Divergence, and I came across a problem:

Given a two dimensional vector field: $$ F=\langle e^{\sin{x}}+y^2, x^2+y^2 \rangle$$

And then I am also given that there is a oriented curve $C$ such that it starts at point $(1,2)$ and moves along a line segment to the point $(1,4)$, then moves along another line segment to the point $(2,4)$, and then moves one more time along a third line segment back to $(1,2)$.

How do I calculate $$\int_C F\,dr?$$

My thoughts for this were that we could parameterize the movement of $C$? I would like to solve this using Green's Theorem if possible. But, I am very vague on this and I would like some explained help on this concept, since I will be having a test in the near future.

Comment: Your integral is $I = \iint 2(x-y)\,dx\,dy$. You can see limits from picture: $$I = \int\limits_1^2 dx \int\limits_{y=2x}^{y=4} 2(x-y)\,dy$$

Comment: @MichaelGaluza Why 2x? Why not x?

Comment: Because points $(1,2)$ and $(2,4)$ lies on it.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza Does it come out to -2/3. Can you verify this?

Comment: @lolinda For concept of Multiple Integration and Vector Calculus please watch these lectures https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCoQtwIwAmoVChMIz-_BnrWNxwIVjh-OCh3NcAgO&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DtyfZQ2NZfqo&ei=4KG_Vc__MI6_uATN4aFw&usg=AFQjCNHqCghy_W7RuEEWInlFlKV82svqiw&sig2=wzo1PWobOWfeWLMFz0wX1A

Comment: $\int_{2x}^4 2(x-y)\,dy = 2x(4-2x) - 16 + 4x^2$; integrate by $x$ from $1$ to $2$, and you should get $-4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\vec{F} = (e^{\sin{x}}+y^2, x^2+y^2) = (M,N)$$
From Green's theorem $$\int_C{F}\;\mathrm{d}r = \iint_R \text{curl }\vec{F} \; \mathrm{d}A$$
Since the curl of $\vec{F}$ is $N_x - M_y$
\begin{align*}
\iint_R \text{curl }\vec{F} \; \mathrm{d}A &= \iint_R 2x-2y\; \mathrm{d}A\\
&= 2\iint_R x-y\; \mathrm{d}A
\end{align*}
To convert to iterated integral we need to know the bounds of $y$ and $x$. If we fix some $x$ notice that $y$ ranges from the line that passes through $(1,2)$ and $(2,4)$ (the line $y = 2x$) to $y = 4$. $x$ ranges from $1$ to $2$. So now we have the iterated integral:
\begin{align*}
2\int_1^2\int_{2x}^{4} x-y \;\mathrm{d}y \;\mathrm{d}x &= 2\int_1^2\left(xy-\frac{y^2}{2}\bigg|_{2x}^4\right)\;\mathrm{d}x \\
&= 2\int_1^2\left(4x-8\right)-(2x^2-2x^2)\;\mathrm{d}x \\
&= 2\int_1^2 4x-8\; \mathrm{d}x \\
&=-4
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Using Green's Theorem. Now you have to evaluate double integral over region i have drawn instead of parametrization of line 3 times. Hope i have helped you

We have to compute

$\int F.dr $ over 3 lines given in your question

So we use Greens Theorem to avoid parametrization of line three times.Given our vector field

M= $e^{sinx} + y^{2}$

N=$ x^{2} + y^{2}$

So using Green's Theorem we have

$\int F.dr $ over 3 lines given in your question = $ \iint\limits_{R} \frac{\partial N}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\mathrm{d}A $, where R is region of Triangle having vertices as $(1,2)$ $(1,4)$ and $(2,4)$

So we putting values of partials we get,

$ \iint\limits_{R} 2(x-y) \mathrm{d}A $

Now i hope you can take from here.It is simple double integral

**EDIT**

We have our double integral as

$ \iint\limits_{R} 2(x-y)dydx $ .We have limits as , $y$ goes from $2x$ to $4$ and $x$ goes from $1$ to $2$. When you write equations for three lines, from there you will find your y limits as i have already mentioned

Comment: *Please don't do that, use latex*

Comment: @MichaelGaluza oh yes sure i will do once i learn about it

Comment: Your reputation is over 500, and you have not one badge. You *must* use latex. It's not a forum for posting pictures.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza Sorry i will edit my question at once

Comment: @MichaelGaluza Can you help me with this?Can you help me find the limits of integration too? And I saw that in my book that whenever it goes clockwise we have to do -C to get positive orientation. Am I right?

Comment: @TaylorTed Can you help me to find the limits of integration. I think I can handle it from there.

Comment: @TaylorTed I know that much already, I need help finding the limits of integration.

Comment: @lolinda i have added limits to my answer.Hope that helps

Comment: You just copied from @MichaelGaluza

Comment: @lolinda i did not copy from anyone, it was only i saw afterwards his answer